# Update DNS Zone in different resource group using BICEP

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I need up update a DNS Zone during a BICEP deployment. The zone already exists in another resource group.

I know I should be able to pull an existing resource in a different RG, but the methods I try do not work.

**Method 1:**

This reports error

> "A resource's computed scope must match that of the Bicep file for it
> to be deployable. This resource's scope is computed from the "scope"
> property value assigned to ancestor resource "zone". You must use
> modules to deploy resources to a different scope.bicep(BCP165)"

```
resource zone 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2023-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: 'xxxx-xxxx.com'  
  scope:resourceGroup('xxxx-Bicep-xxxx-Deploy1')
}

resource record 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2023-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'cname update'
  parent: zone
  properties: {
    TTL: 1200
    CNAMERecord:{
      cname:'record'
    }
  }  
}
```

So I used a module.

**Method 2:**

This reports error:

> This expression is being used in an assignment to the "parent"
> property of the "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME" type, which
> requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the
> deployment. Properties of getthezone which can be calculated at the
> start include "name".bicep(BCP120)

File 1

```
module getthezone 'getdnszone.bicep' = {
  name: 'zoneget'
}

resource record 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2023-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'cname update'
  parent: getthezone.outputs.thezone
  properties: {
    TTL: 1200
    CNAMERecord:{
      cname:'tuemp'
    }
  }  
}
```

File 2

```
resource zone 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2023-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: 'xxx-xxxx.xxx'  
  scope:resourceGroup('xxxx-Bicep-xxxx-Deploy1')
}

output thezone object = zone
```

If I change the output from file 2 to string and use that, I get error:

> This expression is being used in an assignment to the "parent"
> property of the "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME" type, which
> requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the
> deployment. Properties of getthezone which can be calculated at the
> start include "name".bicep(BCP120)

I'm missing something. How can I update a DNS record in another resource group using BICEP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

file 1

```
module dothezone 'dothezone.bicep' = {
  name: 'zoneget'
  scope:resourceGroup('xxxx-Bicep-xxxx-Deploy1')
}
```

File 2

```
resource zone 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2023-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: 'xxx-xxxx.xxx'  
}

resource record 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2023-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'cname update'
  parent: zone
  properties: {
    TTL: 1200
    CNAMERecord:{
      cname:'tuemp'
    }
  }  
}
```